# Effect of Page Specification on Vault.Trackby

Tags: corda

I recently got more results than I bargained for when testing my cordapp with the `vault.trackby` function and blew the default page specification limit.
So to confirm my understanding of how the page specification works with `trackby` in relation to the initial snapshot, here's a scenario and a couple of questions.

Lets say I have a 1000 states in the vault that meet my query criteria.
So I call `vault.trackby` with a page specification where the pageNumber is 1 and the page size is 250

1. I assume I will get the first 250 results with the initial snapshot, is this correct?
2. Will the remaining 750 results comeback with the updates? Or will only new updates come back. Leaving the other 750 states only accessible by querying again using `trackBy` or `queryBy`, page 2,3,4 etc.

I hope that makes sense.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Specific answers to your questions:

1) Correct

2) Only new updates will be streamed back, and you would need to issue another `queryBy` (do not use `trackBy` again) explicitly asking for page 2, 3, 4.
However, *beware* that subsequent queries (eg. for pages 2, 3, 4) *may* include new results - including already streamed updates from the initial `trackBy` query - as each snapshot query is unique at a specific moment in time.

The intended usage pattern of `trackBy` is to obtain a *bounded* snapshot (defined by the associated Query Criteria) that fits in a single page, and thus guarantee atomicity of streaming updates (eg. no duplicates).

A recommended usage pattern is to:

a) first issue a snapshot (`queryBy`) query using some bounded criteria (eg. all entries older than 24 hours), followed by a

b) second streaming (`trackBy`) query using a constrained bounded criteria  (eg. all entries in the last 24 hours)

So in summary, the pagination semantic of `trackBy` should be used with caution and with the understanding that subsequent page requests may contain different results  (based on any CRUD operations effected since the original `trackBy` query)